# Python PDF Timetable parser

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I have a PDF file containing a structured timetable with information such as days, sessions, staff, rooms, types, start times, and end times. Here's a simplified example:

[image: simplified example]

I want to parse this PDF and extract the timetable information into a list of dictionaries in Python. Each dictionary should represent a session with the day, session number, staff, room, type, start time, and end time. Additionally, there could be empty sessions that need to be handled.

I've tried using libraries like PyPDF2, tabula-py, and Camelot, but having trouble getting the desired results, as it kinda give's my chaotic for processing data

```
['Monday', 'Staff', 'Room', 'Type', 'Start', 'End', 'Tuesday', 'Staff', 'Room', 'Type', 'Start', 'End', 'Wednesday', 'Staff', 'Room', 'Type', 'Start', 'End', 'Thursday', 'Staff', 'Room', 'Type', 'Start', 'End', 'Friday', 'Staff', 'Room', 'Type', 'Start', 'EndSession 1 Session 2 Session 3 Session 4 Session 5 Session 61.5 1.510:45 12:4509:15 11:15Employer Set Task Theory/PracticalST26 ST26Sean Farrelly Zwelo DubeSession 1 Session 2 Session 3 Session 4 Session 5 Session 61.5 1.5 1.5 1.510:45 12:45 14:45 16:3009:15 11:15 13:30 15:00Theory/Practical Theory/Practical Theory/Practical Theory/PracticalST26 ST26 ST26 ST26Zwelo Dube Sean Farrelly Sean Farrelly Sean FarrellySession 1 Session 2 Session 3 Session 4 Session 5 Session 61.5 1.5 110:45 12:45 14:4509:15 11:15 13:45Theory/Practical PDP Tutorial Theory/PracticalST26 ST26Sean Farrelly TBC - Student Tutor 2\t \t \t Zwelo DubeSession 1 Session 2 Session 3 Session 4 Session 5 Session 61.5 1.5 1.5 1.510:45 12:45 15:00 16:3009:15 11:15 13:30 15:00Theory/Practical Theory/Practical Self Study Self StudyST26 ST26 ST26 ST26Session 5 Session 6', 'Zwelo Dube Zwelo Dube Independent (Self-Directed) Study Independent (Self-Directed) StudyCourse Code: RITP046D1A (Year 1) - (note generic parent code is RITP037F1A)', 'Group: Grp A', 'Session 1 Session 2 Session 3 Session 4Course Title: T-Level - Technical Qualification in Digital Production, Design and Development', 'Updated on: 06-Sep-23', '']
```

so just dk what the best way to do that

Could someone provide a tips or a Python code example that effectively extracts this information from the PDF and organizes it into a list of dictionaries

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you try [Adobe PDF parse service](https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-extract-api/)?

Comment: Yes, not a bad idea, I will try it soon, but so far managed to realise it using `camelot`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solution worked for me:

```
import camelot

file = "data.pdf"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file)
content = []

for table in tables:
    content.append(table.df.values.tolist())

week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

def parse_schedule(schedule_data):
    schedule = {}
    current_day = None
    current_session = None

    for i in range(len(schedule_data)):
        lines = schedule_data[i]

        for line in lines:
            parts = line.split('\n')
            print(parts)
            if parts[0] in week_days:
                current_day = parts[0]
                schedule[current_day] = {}
            elif parts[0] == "" or parts[0] == "1.5":
                continue
            elif parts[0].startswith("Session") and len(parts) > 1:

                session_name = parts[0]
                current_session = session_name
                schedule[current_day][current_session] = {}
                schedule[current_day][current_session]["Staff"] = parts[1]
                if parts[2].startswith("ST"):
                    schedule[current_day][current_session]["Room"] = parts[2]
                    schedule[current_day][current_session]["Type"] = parts[3]
                    schedule[current_day][current_session]["Start"] = parts[4]
                    schedule[current_day][current_session]["End"] = parts[5]
                else:
                    schedule[current_day][current_session]["Type"] = parts[2]
                    schedule[current_day][current_session]["Start"] = parts[3]
                    schedule[current_day][current_session]["End"] = parts[4]

    return schedule

timetable = {}

for i in range(len(content)):
    schedule = parse_schedule(content[i])
    for day in list(schedule.keys()):
        
        timetable[day] = schedule[day]

print(timetable)
```

output:

```
{'Monday': {'Session 1': {'Staff': 'Zwelo Dube', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '09:15', 'End': '10:45'}, 'Session 2': {'Staff': 'Zwelo Dube', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '11:15', 'End': '12:45'}, 'Session 3': {'Staff': 'Independent (Self-Directed) Study', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Self Study', 'Start': '13:30', 'End': '15:00'}, 'Session 4': {'Staff': 'Independent (Self-Directed) Study', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Self Study', 'Start': '15:00', 'End': '16:30'}}, 'Tuesday': {'Session 1': {'Staff': 'Sean Farrelly', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '09:15', 'End': '10:45'}, 'Session 2': {'Staff': 'TBC - Student Tutor 2(cid:9)(cid:9)(cid:9)', 'Type': 'PDP Tutorial', 'Start': '11:15', 'End': '12:45'}, 'Session 3': {'Staff': 'Zwelo Dube', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '13:45', 'End': '14:45'}}, 'Wednesday': {'Session 1': {'Staff': 'Zwelo Dube', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '09:15', 'End': '10:45'}, 'Session 2': {'Staff': 'Sean Farrelly', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '11:15', 'End': '12:45'}, 'Session 3': {'Staff': 'Sean Farrelly', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '13:30', 'End': '14:45'}, 'Session 4': {'Staff': 'Sean Farrelly', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '15:00', 'End': '16:30'}}, 'Thursday': {'Session 1': {'Staff': 'Sean Farrelly', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Employer Set Task', 'Start': '09:15', 'End': '10:45'}, 'Session 2': {'Staff': 'Zwelo Dube', 'Room': 'ST26', 'Type': 'Theory/Practical', 'Start': '11:15', 'End': '12:45'}}, 'Friday': {}}
```